# Distributing iOS app via ad-hoc creating some record in iTunes connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution, adhoc

I need test my app by other people but I dont have developer 99$ account so I ask my friend with this account to make an ipa file. I need this app now and dev. registration process needs some time. My question is if during this process of creating ipa file via ad-hoc distributing is creating some record in iTunes connect or in his account?

Comment: that particular ipa will be associated with your friend's developer account.  however, nothing preventing you from creating the same app using different bundle id and uploading that to your account and publishing it that way.  just make sure that he use different bundle id than yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think NO, you can not create a .ipa file if you dont have any activate apple account. Because you will have to need to set your code signing settings before making an .ipa file which you can not set without a valid profile. So first of all you should have a paid activate apple account, then create a valid profile for your app, set your app's code signing,.. only when you can make .ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should have a unique bundle id.

Your friend would have to create an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile for this bundle id in iTunes Connect to be able to sign the app. The app can't run if it isn't signed.

Creating the .ipa file or Ad-Hoc distribution will not create any entries on iTunes Connect or your friends Account by itself.